# currency woes with locales

Tags: iphone, locale, currency, nslocale

I have my app correctly displaying the users currency symbol with this line:

```
 NSString *sym = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
```

And when I change the locale of my device the symbol is correct for the selected country.

What I am finding is that the monetary value seems to stay in GBP?

So I have a price set in iTunes Connect at £1.49 but when I change to say Germany €1.49 is displayed and not €1.70?

I was under the impression the price obtained from iTunes Connect by the device would be in the users currency, is this not so?

needless to say am in panic mode....any advise please?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you plan on calling a currency exchange rate webservice every time you display the amount you will want to leave the currency symbol in the original locale(£). The reason for that is because exchange rates fluctuate, which is not programmed for in the API, therefore the price will not automatically update in your code.

When a user connects to iTunes directly they will see the correct price because Apple has already done the currency conversion on their side. Your code will need to do its own conversions.

Comment: The only other way to get it "automatically" would be to send the user's culture along in the iTunes store request and let them convert it for you.

Comment: I'm still confused as I have been informed that a user in Australia saw the correct Australian dollar amount but with a £ symbol so it looked more expensive.  Likewise users in China again saw the correct yuan value but again with the £ symbol making them think the app was far more expensive.  So it looks like when my app obtained the price from iTunes connect it was getting converted?  But since the price tiers have change by Apple now it always display the GBP price????

Comment: How are you getting the price? Are you referring to in the App Store or in your own App.

Answer (score 0):

I get the price like this:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse: (SKProductsResponse *)response {

NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithArray:response.products];

SKProduct *p = [a count] == 1 ? [a objectAtIndex:0] : nil;


// if we have a product store the price, otherwise 

if (p) {

    NSString *sym = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];

    [self setPriceText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",sym, p.price]];

    [self setProductFound:YES];
}
else {

    [self setPriceText:@"Upgrade product not found"];

    [self setProductFound:NO];        
}

[request release];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have now found out that this is the correct way to display a localised price:

```
    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithArray:response.products];

SKProduct *p = [a count] == 1 ? [a objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];

[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

[numberFormatter setLocale:p.priceLocale];

NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:p.price];
```

However I still get the same monetary value no matter what locale I set on the device, from what I am reading in other posts here and in Apple docs I should be seeing locale monetary value???